# PDAL Pipeline Issue: 'Missing :' Limit Separator Error – Seeking Help and Guidance

Tags: json, pipeline, pdal

I'm currently working with PDAL (Point Data Abstraction Library) to process point cloud data, and I'm facing an issue with a specific PDAL pipeline. I've created a pipeline to filter out ground points from a LAS/LAZ file, but I'm encountering a "PDAL: Missing ':' limit separator" error.

Here's the PDAL pipeline I'm using:
{
"pipeline": [
"y:\jb1929_shook_natania_lidar\2023-11-19_14-20-34_surfaceNoise_outlier_rigid.laz",
{
"type": "filters.range",
"limits": "Classification![1:2]"  // Exclude unclassified and non-ground points
},
{
"type": "filters.smrf",
"ignore": "Classification[7]",
"slope": 0.2,
"window": 16.0,
"threshold": 0.15
},
{
"type": "filters.hag_nn",
"returns": "last",
"ignore": "Classification[7]",
"approximate": true
},
{
"type": "filters.range",
"limits": "HeightAboveGround[0:0.4]"  // Keep points up to 0.4 meters above the ground
},
"2023-11-19_14-20-34_surfaceNoise_outlier_rigid_ground_only.laz"
]
}
However, I keep getting the "PDAL: Missing ':' limit separator" error, and I'm not sure what's causing it. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong with my pipeline or provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Any assistance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Pipeline Syntax Review: I reviewed the syntax of my PDAL pipeline carefully to ensure there were no obvious syntax errors or typos.

Documentation Check: I consulted the PDAL documentation to make sure I was using the correct syntax for the filters.range filter's "limits" parameter.

Online Searches: I performed online searches to find similar issues or discussions related to the "Missing ':' limit separator" error in PDAL, but I couldn't find a clear solution that applies to my specific case.

What I was expecting:

I was expecting that the "limits" parameter in the filters.range filter of my PDAL pipeline would correctly specify the range for excluding unclassified and non-ground points. The syntax "Classification![1:2]" seemed appropriate based on my understanding of PDAL's filtering syntax.

However, I'm still encountering the "Missing ':' limit separator" error, and I'm not sure why this issue persists. I'm reaching out to the Reddit community to see if anyone has encountered a similar issue or has suggestions on how to resolve it. Any help or insights are greatly appreciated!